# Rewrite WordPress Standard Feed URL - /feed/ to feed.xml

Tags: urls, htaccess, rss, xml

I want to rewrite http://www.ourdomain.com/feed/ in the .htaccess file

to **http://ourdomain.com/feed.xml**

And we have some other feed URLs to Rewrite. After a search I could not
find the correct solution. I tried a few .htaccess entries, but none of it w
worked.

Or: probably someone knows how to bring rss-feeds into this format (with file-extension) in the url. The requirement is that we use a third party provider which has to read this url, but does not access /feed/ format without the .xml extension.

thanks!

Comment: Could you please include your `.htaccess` attempts? It might be easier and faster to point out how to make them right than research, write, and test them from scratch.

Comment: Handle it in the 404 to trigger XML output based on the URL requested. Or add a URL rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a fake query parameter on the URL to get around those sort of bad restrictions in other pieces of code.

http://example.com/feed/?fakefile=feed.xml